# How to debug Android app with Play services

Tags: android, google-play

I wish to link my Android game to Google Play Games Services but I cannot figure out how to do it with a debug certificate. From what I know, I need to upload an apk to Google for internal testing, which will then create a test certificate to link my app to the services. But, if I launch the app on an emulator, I'm using the Android Studio debug certificate, which cannot be used to link apps. How then such app be debugged? Can a debug certificate be used to link the app after it's been uploaded to internal testing? What is the workflow in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**

Go to:
[Google Cloud Platform Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)

**Step 2.**

Choose there your project and then create a new credential for OAuth client ID in Signing-certificate fingerprint set your debug SHA-1 certificate fingerprint

**Step 3.**

Go to: Google Play Console/Game services/Linked apps

and link your app once again this time it will use debug certificate

---

by default Game services are taking the last credential from Google Cloud Platform so now u should be able to use Google Play Games Services with your debug certificate

Comment: Is there a way to NOT involve the Cloud Platform in this?

Comment: I don't think so because the first credential with release certificate is created automatically if there isn't any.

Comment: I find it strange that developing an app with service integration (which seems a common use case) requires signing in to some another unrelated service.